# How do i query 2 random records from a table for each day in date range?

Tags: t-sql

How would I find 2 random records for each day within a given date range?

For customers between dates '20221201' to '20221205'

Days
01/12/2022  Random user ID 1, Random user ID 2
02/12/2022  Random user ID 1, Random user ID 2
03/12/2022  Random user ID 1, Random user ID 2
04/12/2022  Random user ID 1, Random user ID 2
05/12/2022  Random user ID 1, Random user ID 2

Have so far been experimenting with ordering by New ID however I need 2 random records for each day and would prefer not to run the script for each day separately.

Comment: Use a `PARTITION BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER`'s `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function `row_number()`

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = row_number() over (partition by YourDate order by newid() ) 
 From  YourTable
 Where YourDate between '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-05'
 )
 Select * 
  From  cte 
  Where RN<=2
```